# Strip quotes in PHP for JSON output

Tags: php, json, escaping

I have a string in PHP that contains both single and double quotes.

I am trying to use this string in some JSON output. To do this I need to escape double quotes, slashes, newlines etc.

I thought that addslashes() would do the job but it also escapes single quotes which causes the JSON to fail.

**How can I escape all relevant special characters except for single quotes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json_encode()` will [handle all that for you](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).